# Can RubyMine detect _spec.rb files and show them when clicking Run/Debug?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I'm doing a local Ruby (Not Rails) app and have the following files:

- /lib/my_example.rb
- /spec/my_example_spec.rb

When I select Run or Debug from the Run menu a popup appears and lists some of the *.rb files of the project (usually the files I modified last).

This popup never shows the *_spec.rb files. I have to select the option "Edit configurations" and specifically select the *_spec.rb I want to run.

Is there a way to make RubyMine's Run/Debug popup show me the *_spec.rb files of my project automatically and allow me to choose them?

Comment: If you don't include Ruby tag, nobody will look at your question. Nobody is going to open the questions by RubyMine tag.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: some might. But yeah, I'd guess that most/all rubymine watchers also watch ruby tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that in a single operation, but this might help:

- Pressing `CMD-Shift-T` from `/lib/my_example.rb` should take you to the spec
- From `my_example_spec.rb`, you can press `Ctrl-D` or `Ctrl-R` to debug or run the test